# how to trigger a method in javascript when contents of iframe changes with src of iframe remains same

Tags: javascript, yui, wicket-1.6

I have recently started working on YUI JS and Wicket. I am facing a problem and couldn't solve it for the past few days.

**Here is the problem**:  Am using an `iframe` in my wicket application. I have to resize the `iframe` based on its content changes using *YUI*. Here the problem is when the content changes, still **src** of  the iframe remains same. I tried by adding listeners to the elements of the `iframe` but I was unsuccessful. Please help me out in this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO Krishna!

Comment: `src` is a property of `iframe` element. If the document in an iframe changes its location, it is not reflected to `src` attribute on the parent page.

Comment: Right, and why do you expect the src to change? Can you explain that a bit more?

Comment: Hi dbrin. When I was searching how to detect the change in iframe content, I got answers for detecting the src change of iframe. My requirement is there will be an element in the iframe and its value changes dynamically and now my job is to capture that event when value changes and have to trigger a method in javascript. I have tried the same by using DOMCharacterDataModified but it didnt worked. The reason I found for this was DOMCharacterDataModified listens to events to only elements that are modified by script. Here in my actual case the value of element in iframe is modified by java.

Comment: What causes the content in the iframe to change? Is it the user clicking on something or something else? Is the content being updated with ajax or are you loading a new page entirely?